# Show next tab on button click in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsp

In my jSP page, I have some tabs. A tab has a button. What I want is when I click on the button, it should display the next tab or the tab I am providing with index.

My `index.jsp` is,

```
<div class="navbar btn-navbar">
            <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li id="datacollect" class="active"><a href="#datacollector"
                        target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                    <li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType"><a
                        href="#fromDatabase" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Database</a></li>
                    <li id="fromFile" class="selectDataloadType"><a
                        href="#fromFiles" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            File</a></li>
                    <li id="email" class="selectDataloadType"><a href="#fromEmail"
                        target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load Email</a></li>
                    <li id="webServices" class="selectDataloadType"><a
                        href="#fromWebServices" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                            Load Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#datamap" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                            Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="datacollector">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span8">
                                    <form>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <label class="control-label" for="dataloadType">Data
                                                load Type:</label> <select id="dataloadType" name="dataloadType">
                                                <option>Choose Data load Type</option>
                                                <option value="fromDB">From Database</option>
                                                <option value="fromFile">From File</option>
                                                <option value="email">E-mail</option>
                                                <option value="webServices">Web Services</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <p>
                                                <button id="dataloadNext" class="btn btn-success"
                                                    type="button">Submit</button>
                                            </p>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And the script is

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#dataloadNext").click(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs("active", 2 );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using ***`jquery-1.9.0`*** What is the error here?

***UPDATE 1***

Browser showing error like this

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call `method 'active'                       jquery-1.9.0.js:490`
```

Comment: You tell me, you have shown us everything but you did not say whats wrong or whats the output ?

Comment: When I click on the button, its not going to the next tab with index value 2. Staying in the same tab

Comment: And does your console show any errors ?

Comment: Yes. Please see the **Update 1**. Please help me to get a solution. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is a jQuery-UI error and the JSP is just fine, what I think the problem is that jquery-ui and almost every other javascript framework (bootstrap as you are using for example), must have their elements initialized as of the type I want before doing any work with them.

*e.g* you must say that they are tabs before you switch between them.

**Sample Code Would be**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  //then use them
  $("#dataloadNext").click(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs("active", 2 );
    });
 </script>
```

Hope this helps